# How to remove stopwords through SQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with millions of messages. I want to remove a list of stopwords from each of those message - in SQL

Example input:

```
id  message
-------------------------------
1   we are on top of the world
2   too bad the apple is rotten
3   there is no I in team
4   it matters where you go to
```

Stopwords to remove:

```
in, on, of, to, too
```

Desired output:

```
id  message
-------------------------------
1   we are top the world
2   bad the apple is rotten
3   there is no I team
4   it matters where you go
```

The problem here it, I guess, that either stopword could be at the beginning, in the middle or at the end of the message. So a query like this would be satisfactory:

```
UPDATE table SET message = REPLACE(message, ' in ', '');
UPDATE table SET message = REPLACE(message, ' on ', '');
UPDATE table SET message = REPLACE(message, ' of ', '');
etc...
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: With the given statements you won't replace them at the end of the sentence because there won't be a space at the end. (probably)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get around the problem of not being able to update the stopwords at the beginning and end of the message, what you could do is simply concatenate a space to the beginning and end of each message, *THEN* perform the replace, and then trim the leading/trailing spaces back out:

```
UPDATE tbl 
SET message = TRIM(REPLACE(CONCAT(' ', REPLACE(message, ' in ', ' in  '), ' '), ' in ', ''));
```

**Edit:** What you also have to consider is that stopwords in the middle of the message still have to retain the space after they're replaced, because you don't want to end up with `no I in team` -> `no Iteam`. We take care of this by adding another space after the stopword so that there's two spaces on the right... then, when it gets replaced, that extra space is retained because we are only replacing the stopword having ***one*** space on each side.

---

### [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b05ca/1/0)

Answer (score 3):

If you create a table called stopwords with a field stopword in it holding a list of all your stopwords you can do it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[stopwords](
    [stopword] char(100) NOT NULL
) 

insert into stopwords values ('in');
insert into stopwords values ('on');
insert into stopwords values ('of');
insert into stopwords values ('to');
insert into stopwords values ('too');

-- DEBUG: select message ,stopword, replace(message,CONCAT(' ', stopword , ' '), ' ')
update table 
set message = trim(replace(CONCAT(' ',message, ' '),CONCAT(' ',stopword,' '),' ')) 
from stopwords
where CONCAT(' ', message , ' ')  like CONCAT('% ' ,stopword , ' %')
```

Comment: Would this also cath stopwords at the beginning and end of a message (so with no space before or after the stopword?) Otherwise, @Zane Bien his option seems a smart solution for that :-)